# MVC Custom Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider

I have a custom membership provider that I've specified to be used in my `web.config` file for an MVC3 project.  I assumed that it would be used in place of the built in membership provider since I'm specifying its use like so:

```
<system.web>
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMySQLMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add
      connectionStringName="dbConn"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="true"
      passwordFormat="Hashed"
      maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="25"
      minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
      passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
      applicationName="/jp2012"
      name="CustomMySQLMembershipProvider"
      type="NameSpace.CustomMySqlMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>
</system.web>
```

Do I have to do something in my code to get it to override the default membership provider?  Right now I can access it like this:

```
CustomMySqlMembershipProvider membership = 
    (CustomMySqlMembershipProvider)Membership.Providers["CustomMySQLMembershipProvider"];
```

Is there a way that I can get it to be automagically overriden using the `web.config` file so I don't have to hardcode my implementations name?  Something more like this:

```
MembershipProvider membership = new MembershipProvider();
```

Any ideas?  Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was actually with how I declared my membership.  The line

```
type="NameSpace.CustomMySqlMembershipProvider"
```

did not specify the assembly that my custom membership provider was defined in.  I right clicked on my project, selected properties, and got the assembly name from the field marked `Assembly name`.

So if my assembly name was `AName`, then this line should have been

```
type="NameSpace.CustomMySqlMembershipProvider, AName"
```

Thank you @Eranga for attempting to help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Your Membership provider is the default provider in your case. You don't need to explicitly cast the provider unless you have additional functionality in your provider.

For example when you call `Membership.GetUser()` it will call your membership prover's `GetUser(...)` method.

Comment: How can I get it to call my Initialize method?  I have code in there that initializes variables used throughout the implemented methods.

Comment: @JesseBuesking You have to override the `Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)` to do initialization.

Comment: I've implemented `public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)` already, but it's not currently being called by default.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JesseBuesking It will be called only one time(because Asp.Net keeps only single instance of the MembershipProvider) and you have access your provider **through the Asp.Net API** (eg `Membership.GetUser()`) for `Initialize` method to be called.